# Android Import AppAuth Library as a module

Tags: android, appauth

I need to modify a class in the AppAuth library https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android I have trided importing the library module from the source as a module via Android Studio, but it errors on compiling since the app auth library module references gradle config files in external folders outside of the module folder, if I copy those files over (it's a config folder), then I get yfrog plugin compilation errors. So I would like to know the correct way to import this library into my android project so I can modify the classes. Thanks.